# Multiple languages in HUD and dash

Tags: unity-dash, hud

Is it possible to have multi-language support for HUD and dash?
For example, on the Dash I would like to be able to search for "files" (English) and "dateien" (German) or on the HUD search for "open" (English) and "öffnen" (German) and receive the same result.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in 13.10, don't know about earlier versions